# Can I use full path for importing modules and still uses `@types`?

Tags: typescript

For example, let's say I do `npm install localforage @types/localforage`, and then I have `src/storage.ts` which is a module. Can I do:

```
import localforage from "../node_modules/localforage/dist/localforage.min"
```

...while still being helped by type definitions from `@types/localforage`?

I know `tsconfig.json` has `paths` field to map modules but it didn't work for me.

```
{
  "baseUrl": "/",
  "paths": {
    "node_modules/localforage/dist/localforage.min": ["localforage"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Any reason not to `import localforage from "localforage"` ?

Comment: I'm trying to use browser native ES module system, and AFAIK I can't just do `from "localforage"` in browsers.

Comment: you could you a bundler that outputs native modules (parcel?)

Comment: That's a viable option, but I would be happy if there is a way to do this without requiring a bundler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the `localforage` package has its own typings in `typings/localforage.d.ts` (so you don't need to use `@types/localforage`), but the typings file doesn't get loaded when you import a file in the package rather than the entire package.  Since the typings file defines the `LocalForage` interface globally, you can do this:

```
///<reference path="./node_modules/localforage/typings/localforage.d.ts"/>

// @ts-ignore
import * as localforage_real from "./node_modules/localforage/dist/localforage.min";
const localforage: LocalForage = localforage_real;
console.log(localforage);
```

(If the `LocalForage` interface were defined in a module, it would be a little trickier.)

But it's going to be a pain to do this for every module you use, so I would recommend looking into a bundler that can convert `import * as localforage from 'localforage'` into something that works in the browser.